# Encrypting MySQL database with AES

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a web app in PHP & MySQL to store my passwords & logins as well as some other info related to my business.

I want to be able to encrypt certain sensitive fields using AES encryption, not one way hashing.

I want it so that my sensitive data can only be viewed when I log in using my unique password. It should be invisible to hackers and system administrators.

I do not want my unique password stored anywhere in the database.

Is this possible? If so, how?

In my research I came across this answer to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27320759/8057474

Can anyone confirm this is the correct approach?

Many thanks.

Comment: One big issue to that approach is that you will have only one key for all users and this will be used to encrypt all user data. That approach only attempts to mask the key using the individual user's password so it will appear different for all users but once a hacker gets access to your source code and gets the common master key, then all your data is still compromised.

Comment: Once I get a hashed/salted username.password match can I use the password as the decryption key? That way each user has their own decryption key (using mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt?)

Comment: Are you saying you want to encrypt all data associated to individual users depending on their own decryption keys?

This will be a nightmare (as discussed in your linked discussion) because you will have to decrypt and encrypt all associated tables if the user changes password. Good luck recovering data when you forget to re-encrypt a table